Телеграм бот aiogram 3.x | Как достать текст из данного набора данных?
Приходит текст ID KEY: {'1': 'name1', '2': 'name2', '3': 'name3', '4': 'name4', '5': 'name5', '6': 'name6', '7': 'name7', '8': 'name8'}
!!!Данные всегда разные, меняются цифра и имена. Мне нужно не конкретно из этого текста подставить, а подставлять уже полученные данные.
Мне надо раскидать по кнопкам 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8 текст из данных выше, т.е. должны получиться кнопки, где текст кнопки будет соответствовать name1-name2-name3-name4-name5-name6-name7-name8
    key_id = data.get_charter() #Это функция, которая выдает мне данные
                    char1 = key_id[1] # Здесь константы, где должны быть char1 = name1 и т.д.
                    char2 = key_id[2]
                    char3 = key_id[3]
                    char4 = key_id[4]
                    char5 = key_id[5]
                    char6 = key_id[6]
                    char7 = key_id[7]
                    char8 = key_id[8]
                    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[
                        InlineKeyboardButton(char1), InlineKeyboardButton(char2)]
                        [InlineKeyboardButton(char3), InlineKeyboardButton(char4)]
                        [InlineKeyboardButton(char5), InlineKeyboardButton(char6)]
                        [InlineKeyboardButton(char7), InlineKeyboardButton(char8) 
                                                               ]])  
                   await message.answer("", reply_markup=markup)


Могу предложить такой вариант
test = {'1': 'name1', '2': 'name2', '3': 'name3', '4': 'name4', '5': 'name5', '6': 'name6', '7': 'name7', '8': 'name8'}

for item in test:
    print(test[item])

вывод:
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
name7
name8


сейчас попробую, спасибо

Ну это же обычный словарь. Вам нужны из него только значения, а ключи не нужны, значит берём от него .values() и делаем списковое включение:
key_id = data.get_charter()

buttons = [InlineKeyboardButton(val) for val in key_id.values()]
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons, row_width=2)

await message.answer("", reply_markup=markup)

Присваивания вида char1 = key_id[1] вообще не нужны.

Ого, понял, спасиб. А как это разнести по восьми кнопкам? Чтобы в кнопке 1 было значение соответствующее первому значению, т.е. в первой кнопке должно быть name1, во второй кнопке name2 и т.д. Я заранее извиняюсь за тупняк, если там надо просто циферки добавить в скобки

@Torrtozzo Это уже готовый код, создающий весь ваш список кнопок, ничего дополнительно делать не нужно. Собственно, циклы в языках программирования как-раз для того и придумали, чтобы не нужно было повторять одинаковый код много раз. Списковое включение - это такой вариант цикла в питоне, который сразу создаёт готовый список.

А, стоп, у вас там матрица 4x2, я подумаю, как её сделать.

Понял, еще раз спасибо. Я пока не особо шарю в питоне. Хорошо, что есть добрые люди

там всего 8 кнопок по порядку, главное просто чтоб кнопки были с соответствующими значениями)))

Там есть аргумент, который ширину строки задает

@ClarkDevlin Вот я и думаю, наверняка эти пляски с бубном не нужны, что-то готовое есть

К примеру InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2), в строке по 2 кнопки будет.
Если через билдер создавать, то, по-моему, будет kb.adjust(2)

@ClarkDevlin Ага, я уже нашёл доку, спасибо )

Кнопочки сделать не получилось, т.к. один используемый мной враппер(или не он) ругается TypeError: BaseModel.init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given... Буду искать в чем проблема

key_id = data.get_charter()  print(key_id) в терминале выдает {'1308': 'name1', '1112': 'name2', '1309': 'name3', '1005': 'name4', '1205': 'name5', '1006': 'name6', '1307': 'name7', '1306': 'name8'}

И мне еще надо туда callback дату запихать... Чтоб потом через callback по нажатию отправлять иные сообщения >_<

Ну нормальный словарь. key_id.values() должен нормально ключи отдавать.
